# Inserting a Variable Into SQL Table

Tags: javascript, sql, html

I cannot seem to get user entered data into a table and then printed.

Here is my code thus far:

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
function submit() {
        var input = document.getElementById("save_name").value;
        localStorage.setItem("inputed_name", input);
        var msg;
        db.transaction(function (tx) 
        {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log varchar(50))');
            tx.executeSql('delete from LOGS'); // Clears table (for debugging)

            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (1, localStorage.inputed_name)');
            msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
            document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = msg;
        });

        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length, i;
                msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
                document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML += msg;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log + "</b></p>";
                    document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML += msg;
                }
            }, null);
        });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="status" name="status">Status Message</div>
<p>Enter data: <input type="text" id="save_name" name="inputed_name" /><br/></p>
<p><button onclick="submit()" type="button">Submit Data</button></p> <!--Should print data from the table-->
</body>
</html>
```

I got the "template"/start for this from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

**Solved Below**

Now I want to add two variables to my table, the original log variable and a second to act as a time stamp

```
function submit() 
{
    var input = document.getElementById("save_name").value;
    var msg;
    var time_stamp = new Date();

    db.transaction(function (tx) 
    {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id auto_increment, date_time varchar(128), log varchar(64))');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (log, date_time) VALUES (?, ?)', [input, time_stamp]); // <--Problem here!
        msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
        document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = msg;
    });
}
```

The rest of the code is the same as above.
I would think this would work but when I test it nothing gets in the table.

Comment: Even though I don't know what database this is for (and, like Mark Byers, would like to know), I think the issue has to do with the `localStorage.inputed_name` reference in the insert query.

Comment: @MarkByers: Looks like local storage in the browser for JavaScript, which is based off Sqlite, for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @Mitch: Where does `db` come from? Also, show your HTML. You can't use `getElementById` with the `name` attribute from an element.

Comment: It is what Cory said.
@AndriyM I suspected that was the problem but I can not find a method to insert my variable into the table

Comment: @MitchellByrd: See my answer below. You need to "parameterize" your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to change the way you're getting and inserting your values (also, you had a syntax error in the SQL on this line):

```
var input = document.getElementById('someId').value;

...
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (1, ?)', [input]);
...
```

I think you can forget about the `localStorage` variable altogether, unless you need to persist those values.

Comment: yep, or something like: 'INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (1, ' + localStorage.getItem("inputed_name") + ')'

Comment: @MitchellByrd: You're welcome. Also, welcome to StackOverflow. When you can, remember to mark an answer that solved your issue by clicking the checkmark next to it. This keeps your answer ratio up and will lower the risk of people ignoring your questions.

Comment: @SeanW: Cory's is the preferred method. Concatenating arguments like you are suggesting would open the OP to SQL injection. Besides, if `log` is a string type column, quotes would need to be added around the value.

Comment: @Cory Thanks. Now a quickie question, I am wanting to insert two variables. Would I do something like "tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (log, date_time) VALUES (?, ?)', [input, time]);"

Comment: @Cory when I do that nothing actually makes it into the table. Should I make another question with my source code and link it to you?

Comment: @MitchellByrd: Let's keep it all on one thread. Just amend your original question.

Answer (score 0):

To insert multiple variables into the table, use the following format.

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CacheRequest (key,value) VALUES (?,?)',[variableKey,variableValue]);
```