# Is it possible to update data in my SQL database with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm starting to learn some of SQL with javascript and i want to put my variable ("Val_Points from javascript") into a table ("Usuarios") of a user (ex : Robert). It's this posible via Javascript or there are some other methods ?

```js
var Val_Points = 0; /* Variable */
$('.btn').click(function() {
  Val_Points += 5; /* value +5 */
  /* Update individual SQL Data
  var UpdateSQL = dbConn.executeUpdate('UPDATE Usuarios SET Points="$Val_Points" WHERE Username="$_SESSION[username]"'); 
*/
  $('#exp_bar').val(Val_Points);
});
```

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 require 'connect.php';
$username_session = $_SESSION['username']; /* "Robert" Session */
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Usuarios` WHERE usuario='$username_session'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Points</p>
<progress id ="exp_bar" value="0" max="100"></progress><br>
<button class="btn">+1</button>
```

Also i was seeing a script that simplifly this https://hiddentao.github.io/squel/ Maybe could be more readable in scripting with this. Any help?

**EDIT**

I tried to do all of this with php via $_SESSION

```html
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
$username_session = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Usuarios` WHERE username='$username_session'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if(empty($_SESSION['Val_Points'])){

    $Val_Points_Session = $_SESSION['Val_Points'] = 0; 
}


 echo "<form action='' method='POST'>
   <progress id ='exp_bar' value='".$_SESSION['Val_Points']++."' max='100'></progress>
   <input class='btn' type='submit'  value='Increase val' /> 
 </form>";

 echo $_SESSION['Val_Points']; /* Show current variable */
$Update_SQL = "UPDATE Usuarios SET Points='$Val_Points_Session' WHERE username='$username_session'";

?>
```

But it doesn't update the table, the table keeps with the same value

Username      Points
Robert          0

Comment: You are trying to execute php in your js? You have to make a call to the server (e.g. $.ajax ) and there the update can be done. I don't know why adding the php tag was refused...

Comment: It's possible from where i see some examples like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232865/inserting-a-variable-into-sql-table but it didn't helped me also the php tag was added!

Comment: Ok with this library it seems to be possible to execute SQL from JS, I just can't imagine how this can be really safe, I prefer to have a layer in between, sorry can't help you with that only "traditional" way.

Comment: All i want to do is use a variable (Val_Points) from the javascript and update it into a query, i bet that  there are another way to do this but i can't figure out. It's possible to create a variable going +5 from the HTML button with php and update it into a query? I'm new on this and i'm really confused.

Comment: Yes it is possible can give a template... and it is indeed very confusing at first: most important always remind yourself that JS is running on the client side and php on the server side (although you can add javascript to your php it won't be interpreted on the server).

Comment: Criss I think you are missing the basics. There for I suggest you read this tutorial http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/04/voting-system-with-jquery-php

Comment: @Criss added a comment under my answer. Did you add the ajax tag? To me it seems you want to do it really oldschool by reloading the whole page, just 1 php file is possible in this case and no AJAX.

Comment: @Criss it would even be possible without any JS then just by using the form in its original way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is it possible to insert data with Javascript to an SQL database**

*Simple answer is no. Not **just** with Javascript.*

For understanding this you need to know the difference between `client-side` and `server-side`.

**Client-side**

Operations that are performed by the client. The operations are made by the computer/software of the user. This also means the client can modify the data how ever he want.

**Server-side**

Operations that are performed by the server. The operations are made on an server and uses just the information that is send by the client. After the data is recived the client can not modify it.

[image]

Your database is on the `server-side` its on your server. The client has no direct acces to this database, so you need to send the data from the `client-side` to the `server-side`. This can be done with `javascript`.

*So how to do this.*

In your case you wanna combine `Javascript` (client) with `PHP` (server). Via `PHP` we insert the data to your `SQL` database.

[image]

**Example**

*Javascript / Jquery(!)*

We going to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). This is an function out of the jQuery framework and makes an request to your server.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "phpfile.php",
        data: { label: "value" },
        method: "POST"
    });

    request.done(function() {
        // Do something after its done.
    });
 });
```

*PHP*

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
      // do your database stuff.
      // the data you send from the client is in the $_POST array.
      // for example $_POST['label']
    }

?>
```

Comment: Given my comments are no longer relevant, I'll be deleting them.  I've also given this answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

**"Standard" approach**

`foo.php` is the site which contains a button and includes a script:

```
<button id="update-btn">update</button>
...
<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

`foo.js` adds the on click handler:

```
$('#update-btn').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'fooHandler.php',
        'method': 'POST',
        'data': {'sid': ..., 'action': 'update', 'value': ...}
        /* 'success': function(data) { ... } */
        /* 'error': function ... */
    });
});
```

`fooHandler.php` handles requests to the server from the clients:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['sid'], $_POST['action'])) {
    /* TODO check if valid session */
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'update') {
      /* check if the rest is in order */
      if (isset($_POST['value'] and is_numeric($_POST['value'])) {
        /* TODO execute query */
      }
    } elseif ($_POST['action'] == ...) {
      ...
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: @Criss you can also use `.submit` instead of `.click` to add a submit handler to a form instead of click to a button (and add the ajax command there) and make sure you return false so the form is not actually sent. You can refresh other values on the site like `$('#counter-lbl').html('new content');` and don't need to reload the whole page. I would really create at least 2 php files (content + request handler) or it gets extremely confusing.